# Unable to display a reversed number in C++

Tags: c++, reverse

I'm having difficulty printing a reversed number. The algorithm is working as expected for the reversal of the user's input but cannot display correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

 int rem, OriValue, InValue2 = 0, InValue = 0;//rem = remainder,InValue = User input
 bool neg = false; // Boolean Variable to remember input value

 //Request customer to enter a int value
 cout << "Enter any decimal integer value >= 0:";
 cin >> InValue;
 OriValue = InValue;
 if(InValue < 0)
  {
   neg = true;
   InValue = -InValue;
   cout << "Input value is negative :" << InValue <<"\n";
   }
   else if (InValue > 0 )

   cout << "Input value is positive:"<< InValue <<"\n";
   do
   {
   rem = (InValue % 10);
   cout << "Remainder value:"<< rem << "\n";
   InValue = InValue / 10;

   }
   while (InValue != 0);
   cout << OriValue << " in reverse is " << InValue << "\n";
   // Here is an example of the output:
   // -123 in reverse 321
   return 0;
}
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: You keep dividing `inValue` by 10 until it's zero. Then you print it and it's, of course, zero, since that's the exit condition for your loop. You need to create another variable to hold the reversed value as you go.

Comment: Thanks ggorlen, I just add a other variable but I only get 1. do
    {
        rem = (InValue % 10);
        cout << "Remainder value:"<< rem << "\n";
        Rev  = rem;
        InValue = InValue / 10;

Answer (score 0):

This shoule do the work. Check the comments in the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

 int rem, OriValue, InValue2 = 0, InValue = 0;//rem = remainder,InValue = User input
 int reverseVal = 0; // Add this variable to store the reverse number
 bool neg = false; // Boolean Variable to remember input value

 //Request customer to enter a int value
 cout << "Enter any decimal integer value >= 0:";
 cin >> InValue;
 OriValue = InValue;
 if(InValue < 0)
  {
   neg = true;
   InValue = -InValue;
   cout << "Input value is negative :" << InValue <<"\n";
   }
   else if (InValue > 0 )

   cout << "Input value is positive:"<< InValue <<"\n";
   do
   {
           rem = (InValue % 10);
           cout << "Remainder value:"<< rem << "\n";
           InValue = InValue / 10;
           // Add this to store
           reverseVal = reverseVal*10 + rem;

   }
   while (InValue != 0);
   cout << OriValue << " in reverse is " << reverseVal << "\n";
   // Here is an example of the output:
   // -123 in reverse 321
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dev, Is there another way to save reverseVal besides using that formula? reverseVal = reverseVal*10 + rem?

Comment: Another way is to save the `rem` in an array, index-wise, and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stored your reversed variable anywhere, and `n == 0` is when your loop terminates. When you print `n` after your loop ends, it has to be 0 as you're seeing. The solution is to store your remainders as you divide down `n`.

Here are a couple options for achieving this.

Using `stringstream`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int original_value, n;
    stringstream ss;

    cout << "Enter an integer >= 0:";
    cin >> original_value;
    n = original_value;

    if (n < 0) {
        n = -n;
        ss << '-';
    }

    while (n > 0) {
        ss << n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    cout << original_value << " in reverse is " << ss.str() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Using `reverse`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = -1234;
    string rev = to_string(n);
    reverse(rev.begin() + (rev[0] == '-' ? 1 : 0), rev.end());

    cout << rev << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
Enter an integer >= 0: -1234
-1234 in reverse is -4321
```

If you need an integer at the end, you can always [parse it](https://www.systutorials.com/131/convert-string-to-int-and-reverse/) from the string using `atoi`, `istringstream` or `stoi`.